# Entire View is shifted from right side after rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

My home screen looks like below. I have used Storyboards and size classes for designing the screens, here in this screen collection view is used to display the data.

[image: Screen1]

**After rotating the above home screen if I navigate to any screen using Navigation Controller, then entire view will be shifted from right side(Region shown using red lines in the below screenshot)**. This happens only if I rotate the first screen otherwise everything will be fine and I have not written anything inside the "viewWillTransitionToSize" event of the home screen(first screenshot).

[image]

I checked the height and width of the second screen using "NSLog" in "ViewDidLoad" method, it is coming proper. But why is the screen being shifted from right side?

I have used the below code to load the data using UICollectionView in Home screen (screen 1).

```
   -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {   
    return  arrDashBoardList.count;
}


- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView1 cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";
    //static float fltAlpha =1.0f;

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView1 dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UILabel *lblIcon = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    lblIcon.font = [UIFont fontWithName:chsIcons size:160];
    lblIcon.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:65.0f/255.0f green:168.0f/255.0f blue:119.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    lblIcon.text =[arrDashBoardImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UILabel *lblModule = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
    lblModule.text = [arrDashBoardList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    lblModule.font =[UIFont fontWithName:KlavikaRegular size:25];
    lblModule.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    lblModule.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    return cell;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView1 didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:STORYBOARD_MAIN bundle:nil];
    NavigationViewController_iPhone *navigationController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"contentController"];

    if([[arrDashBoardList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] caseInsensitiveCompare:@“abc”] == NSOrderedSame) //Events
    {
        UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:STORYBOARD_DASHBOARD bundle:nil];
        ABCViewController_iPad *controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"abcController"];
        navigationController.viewControllers = @[controller];
    }
    else if([[arrDashBoardList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] caseInsensitiveCompare:@“xyz”] == NSOrderedSame)//Active Floats
    {
        UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:STORYBOARD_DASHBOARD bundle:nil];
        XYZViewController_iPad  *controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@“xyzController"];
        navigationController.viewControllers = @[controller];
    }

    self.frostedViewController.contentViewController = navigationController;
}
```

Comment: hi are you using auto layout? please put some code here.Thanks.

Comment: I have used Storyboard to design the views, I have edited my question.

Comment: When you select an item, are you loading content on top of the existing content? The line `self.frostedViewController.contentViewController = navigationController;` looks like its embedding the new controller in the existing one? Would you not be better fronting your main screen within a Navigation Controller and simply pushing to your new controller? If you are using content controllers, I would have expected to see you adding the new controller as a child, adding the view of the controller as a subview and setting its frame. From your screen shot it has embedded with a portrait frame.

Comment: Yes it worked,  it saved my day. thanks Rory

Answer (score 0):

I seems like the collectionView is not fill its parent, so you need to find the height and width of its parent and set those value for this layout,

```
[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width
```

Knowing the size of the screen, just set the frame of the UICollectionView to have the width you just figured out.